How do I implement a matrix representing second order differences to solve Whittaker smoothing?
I am trying to use Whittaker-Eilers to smooth noisy data. Using this article to create a method that solves for A in equations 11 & 12 on the page I wrote:
private LUDecomposition buildMatrices(int dataSize, double lambda, int filterOrder) {
        RealMatrix identityMatrix = MatrixUtils.createRealMatrix(dataSize, dataSize);
        RealMatrix orderMatrix = MatrixUtils.createRealMatrix(dataSize - filterOrder, dataSize);

        for (int i = 0; i < dataSize; i++) {
            identityMatrix.setEntry(i, i, 1);

            if (i < dataSize - filterOrder) {
                switch (filterOrder) {
                    case 1:
                        orderMatrix.setEntry(i, i, -1);
                        orderMatrix.setEntry(i, i + 1, 1);
                        break;

                    case 2:
                    default:
                        orderMatrix.setEntry(i, i, 1);
                        orderMatrix.setEntry(i, i + 1, -2);
                        orderMatrix.setEntry(i, i + 2, 1);
                        break;
                }
            }
        }

        RealMatrix A = orderMatrix.transpose().scalarMultiply(lambda).multiply(orderMatrix).add(identityMatrix);
        return new LUDecomposition(A);
    }

The returned LUDecomposition is then used
private void calculateWhittakerSegment(int endIndex, int period) {
        RealVector measValues = new ArrayRealVector(
                ArrayUtils.subarray(data.getYValues(), endIndex - period, endIndex));

        RealVector y = luDecomposition.getP().multiply(MatrixUtils.inverse(luDecomposition.getL())).operate(measValues);

        RealVector adjValues = MatrixUtils.inverse(luDecomposition.getU()).operate(y);
    }

Using a filter order of 1 (equation 8 in the article) results in acceptable results
1st order results
But using a filter order of 2 (equation 17 in the article) does not
2nd order results
I changed the order of operations in solving for A, but did not result in any changed results.

I learned that the LUDecomposition class has its own solver variable within it; using that instead of solving the equation manually fixed the issues when using a second order matrix.
